# Different syntax for method invocation in OO languages

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, syntax

I know:

C++, Java, and tons others:

```
object.method() , object.method(arg)
```

Objective-C:

```
[object method] , [object method:arg]
```

Smalltalk:

```
object method   , object method: arg
```

PHP, Perl

```
object->method(), object->method(arg)
$object->method;
$object->method($arg1, $arg2, ...);
```

OCaml

```
object#method  ,  object#method args
```

CLOS

```
(method object) ,  (method object arg)
```

And even, I have used:

```
method object
method(object)
```

Can you name other alternatives ways of *sending a message to an object* ( I think that would be the correct term )  in different programming languages?

Answer (score 5):

Refer to

[Wikipedia: Comparison of OO Languages -> Method call style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(object-oriented_programming)#Member_access)

Answer (score 1):

Most interesting may be the "generic function" notation - in [CLOS](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) (the O-O part of Common Lisp), they're called like `(method object arg)` (with `defgeneric` for `method` as a generic function and `defmethod` to define its specialization/override); in languages more oriented to algebraic notation, like [Dylan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dylan_(programming_language)) and Python (e.g. with [PEAK](http://peak.telecommunity.com/)), the calls will be more like `method(object, arg)` instead.

The coolest thing about the generic/method approach (which Common Lisp pioneered, AFAIK) is that it doesn't *have* to treat the first object differently from all the others -- method dispatch can happen upon any combination of arguments' runtime types, not just the runtime type of *one* of the arguments (single-argument dispatching is obviously covered as a special case;-).  Say goodbye to [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and all other variants (cfr e.g. [this paper](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/adaptive-patterns/visitor-usage/papers/plop96/variations-visitor-nordberg.ps)) which basically try to simulate multiple dispatching in single-dispatch languages!-)

Comment: +1 I forgot about CLOS ( to be honest, I didn't knew it was OO )

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness’ sake:

While VB.NET normally uses the same style as C#, one can also omit the parentheses on methods and on parameterless functions/constructors:

```
stream.WriteLine "Hello"
Dim x = stream.ReadLine
```

But the IDE will automatically add the parentheses for parametrized method calls (oddly enough, it won’t do the same for functions and constructors).

Furthermore, VB.NET still knows the (somewhat antique) `Call` keyword which once again *forces* parentheses around parametrized method calls:

```
Call stream.WriteLine("Hello") '// is the same as'
stream.WriteLine("Hello")
'// This won’t compile:'
Call stream.WriteLine "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

in Perl, its:

```
$object->method;
$object->method($arg1, $arg2, ...);
```

and the potentially dangerous indirect object syntax (which wont work if you have a sub named method in the current scope:

```
method $object $arg1, $arg2...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Alex Martelli's comment, multi methods in the JVM language Nice

[FiniteStateMachineMultiMethodExample](http://nice.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Doc/FiniteStateMachineMultiMethodExample)

[VisitorPatternMultiMethodExample](http://nice.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Doc/VisitorPatternMultiMethodExample)

and [other examples](http://nice.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Doc/CodeExamples).